# Rails - fill form field with value from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

**Scenario:**
I have a simple_form with a field called "Port". The user should be able to select the **lowest** free port, or override this selection. All reserved ports are saved in the "port"-model. That means every port that is not in that model is available.

**Port Pattern:**
The range is 8080-65080. The step is 100 (8080, 8180, 8280...).

**Env:**
- Rails 5
- sqlite3
- simple_forms
- html.erb

**Question:**
I have absolutely no idea, how to approach this task. I hope for a good tip. I've been searching the web all day long for this task, but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `Port` model has an integer field called `value` for the port number, go to your `port.rb` file and create the following method:

```
def self.available_ports
    unavailable_ports = Port.order(value: :asc).pluck(:value)
    first_port = 8080
    last_port = 65080
    step = 100
    all_ports = (first_port..last_port).step(step).collect { |n| n }
    all_ports - unavailable_ports
end
```

Call `Port.available_ports` and you'll get an array with all available ports with the lowest port being the first port the in array. Then, in your form, display that to the user.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Does `|n| n` create an array from the collection?

Comment: The (first_port..last_port).step(step) returns an object of type `Enumerator`, kinda like a `for`, but contained into a single object. Then, the collect method actually 'runs' this for. The `|n|` is just the value at each loop. The `n` is equal to `return n` (in ruby you do not need to explicitly call `return`). Therefore, the `{ |n| n }` is just a block that is passed to the collect method. That's functional programming. Here you can get more info about: http://flats.github.io/blog/2015/12/02/getting-to-know-rubys-map-and-reduce/